# How do you programmatically update an asset index?

Tags: assets, index

I am trying to update an asset index from a plugin but can't seem to get it to work.  Looking at the docs this seems to me like it should work but it does not. I am on the right path here?

```
$ses = craft()->assetIndexing->getIndexingSessionId();
craft()->assetIndexing->processIndexForSource($ses, null, 7);
```

7 is the id of the asset folder I want to re-index.

Comment: My guess is you're missing `craft()->assetIndexing->getIndexListForSource($sessionId, $sourceId);`. Check how the Asset Index Tool does it in `craft/app/tools/AssetIndexTool.php`.

Comment: You are correct. I was not using it quite right and not understanding exactly how it worked.  This is what I ended up with which works great for me.

  $ses = craft()->assetIndexing->getIndexingSessionId();
  $src = craft()->assetIndexing->getIndexListForSource($ses, 7);
  
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $src['total']; $i++) {
   craft()->assetIndexing->processIndexForSource($ses, $i, 7);
  }

Comment: Awesome glad you got it sorted!  Mind adding that as an official answer instead of a comment? Easier for other people that might have the same question to find.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I ended up with which works great for me.

```
$ses = craft()->assetIndexing->getIndexingSessionId(); 
$src = craft()->assetIndexing->getIndexListForSource($ses, 7); 

for ($i = 1; $i <= $src['total']; $i++) { 
    craft()->assetIndexing->processIndexForSource($ses, $i, 7); 
}
```